# Define CSS classes at runtime in Angular 4

Tags: angular

If I have a template as such:

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

and in the component:

```
    public html = "<div class='title'>Title</div><p>etc. etc.</p>";
    public theme = {
       title: { 
          styles: {
             letterSpacing: '1px',
             fontWeight: 'bold', 
             color: 'gray' 
         }
      }
   };
```

How can I apply the CSS in `theme.title.styles` to the rendered HTML?

One idea I had is to dynamically define the `styles` in the component metadata, but I don't know whether this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use HTML, you can't use ngStyle.

From there, you have two solutions, but given your theme object structure, this only leaves one :

```js
public html = `<div class="title" id="YouNeedACustomId">Title</div><p>etc. etc.</p>`;
let el = document.getElementById('YouNeedACustomId');
for (let prop in theme.title.styles) { el.style[prop] = theme.title.styles[prop]; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I think you can use [**ngStyle**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

Try this hope it will work :)

```
<div [ngStyle] ="getStyle()" [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

And then declare a function in component as

```
getStyle(){
  let styleObject =  theme.title.styles;// or your style object howe so ever you want to define
  return styleObject;
}
```